# sbt one-jar not running if the main class does not have a main method

Tags: scala, sbt, javafx-8, sbt-onejar

I am trying to develop a sample `javafx` application in `scala`. I am using `sbt-one-jar` for packaging the application. My class `MainClass` extends the javafx `Application` which in-turn provides the main method. I am able to right-click in the IDE and run the application successfully. However, after creating the executable jar using sbt-one-jar, while trying to run the jar I am getting main class not found error as below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.app.MainClass.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:339)
>           at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)

I am giving the Main Class in Build.scala as

```
mainClass in oneJar := Some("com.app.MainClass")
```

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My-App");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If I create another scala application and extending App, I am able to run the created one-jar. How can I get around this problem ?